# Rubyでぐるなびapiを叩く際に出るNoMethodErrorを解決したい。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, line

LINEbotの中でぐるなびAPIを使用して情報を所得したく、rubyのcontrollerファイルにコードを記述しているのですが、下記エラーが発生して困っています。お力添えいただけると幸いです。

## エラー文

```
    I, [2019-10-03T00:56:21.711041 #4]  INFO -- : [eb3f8fb8-27c3-413a-93cf-c2b167063968] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 922ms
2019-10-03T00:56:21.711691+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-10-03T00:56:21.711621 #4] FATAL -- : [eb3f8fb8-27c3-413a-93cf-c2b167063968]
2019-10-03T00:56:21.711762+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-10-03T00:56:21.711705 #4] FATAL -- : [eb3f8fb8-27c3-413a-93cf-c2b167063968] NoMethodError (undefined method `sample' for nil:NilClass):
2019-10-03T00:56:21.711817+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-10-03T00:56:21.711765 #4] FATAL -- : [eb3f8fb8-27c3-413a-93cf-c2b167063968]
2019-10-03T00:56:21.711880+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-10-03T00:56:21.711829 #4] FATAL -- : [eb3f8fb8-27c3-413a-93cf-c2b167063968] app/controllers/linebot_controller.rb:48:in `block in callback'
2019-10-03T00:56:21.711881+00:00 app[web.1]: [eb3f8fb8-27c3-413a-93cf-c2b167063968] app/controllers/linebot_controller.rb:28:in `each'
2019-10-03T00:56:21.711883+00:00 app[web.1]: [eb3f8fb8-27c3-413a-93cf-c2b167063968] app/controllers/linebot_controller.rb:28:in `callback'
```

## 該当箇所のコード

**linebot_controller.rb**

```
events.each { |event|
  if event.message['text'] != nil
    place = event.message['text']　　　　 #ここでLINEで送った文章を取得
    result = `curl -X GET https://api.gnavi.co.jp/RestSearchAPI/v3/?keyid=78d2d49f3aa8747a6cc03da01cf41bdd&category_s=RSFST08008&category_s=RSFST08009&#{place}`#ここでぐるなびAPIを叩く#{place}
  else
    latitude = event.message['latitude']
    longitude = event.message['longitude']

    result = `curl -X GET https://api.gnavi.co.jp/RestSearchAPI/v3/?keyid=78d2d49f3aa8747a6cc03da01cf41bdd&category_s=RSFST08008category_s=RSFST08009&latitude=#{latitude}longitude=#{longitude}`　　#ここでぐるなびAPIを叩く
  end

  hash_result = JSON.parse result  #レスポンスが文字列なのでhashにパースする
  shops = hash_result["rest"] #ここでお店情報が入った配列となる
  shop = shops.sample #任意のものを一個選ぶ

  #店の情報
  url = shop["url_mobile"] #サイトのURLを送る
  shop_name = shop["name"] #店の名前
  category = shop["category"] #カテゴリー
  open_time = shop["opentime"] #空いている時間
  holiday = shop["holiday"] #定休日
```

## 全体のコード

```
class LinebotController < ApplicationController
  require 'line/bot'  # gem 'line-bot-api'

  # callbackアクションのCSRFトークン認証を無効
  protect_from_forgery :except => [:callback]

  def client
    @client ||= Line::Bot::Client.new { |config|
      config.channel_secret = ENV["LINE_CHANNEL_SECRET"]
      config.channel_token = ENV["LINE_CHANNEL_TOKEN"]
    }
  end

  def callback
    body = request.body.read

    signature = request.env['HTTP_X_LINE_SIGNATURE']
    unless client.validate_signature(body, signature)
      error 400 do 'Bad Request' end
    end

    events = client.parse_events_from(body)

    #ここでlineに送られたイベントを検出している
    # messageのtext: に指定すると、返信する文字を決定することができる
    #event.message['text']で送られたメッセージを取得することができる
    events.each { |event|
      if event.message['text'] != nil
        place = event.message['text']  #ここでLINEで送った文章を取得
        result = `curl -X GET https://api.gnavi.co.jp/RestSearchAPI/v3/?keyid=78d2d49f3aa8747a6cc03da01cf41bdd&category_s=RSFST08008&category_s=RSFST08009&#{place}`#ここでぐるなびAPIを叩く#{place}
      else
        latitude = event.message['latitude']
        longitude = event.message['longitude']
        puts event.message['latitude']
        puts event.message['longitude']
        puts event.message['latitude'].class
        result = `curl -X GET https://api.gnavi.co.jp/RestSearchAPI/v3/?keyid=78d2d49f3aa8747a6cc03da01cf41bdd&category_s=RSFST08008&category_s=RSFST08009&latitude=#{latitude}&longitude=#{longitude}`#ここでぐるなびAPIを叩くlatitude=#{latitude}longitude=#{longitude}
      end
      hash_result = JSON.parse(result)  #レスポンスが文字列なのでhashにパースする
      shops = hash_result["rest"] #ここでお店情報が入った配列となる
      shop = shops.sample #任意のものを一個選ぶ
      puts shop

      店の情報
      url = shop["url_mobile"] #サイトのURLを送る
      shop_name = shop["name"] #店の名前
      category = shop["category"] #カテゴリー
      open_time = shop["opentime"] #空いている時間
      holiday = shop["holiday"] #定休日

      if open_time.class != String #空いている時間と定休日の二つは空白の時にHashで返ってくるので、文字列に直そうとするとエラーになる。そのため、クラスによる場合分け。
        open_time = ""
     end
     if holiday.class != String
        holiday = ""
      end

      response = "【店名】" + shop_name + "\n" + "【カテゴリー】" + category + "\n" + "【営業時間と定休日】" + open_time + "\n" + holiday + "\n" + url
       case event #case文　caseの値がwhenと一致する時にwhenの中の文章が実行される(switch文みたいなもの)
      when Line::Bot::Event::Message
        case event.type
        when Line::Bot::Event::MessageType::Text,Line::Bot::Event::MessageType::Location
          message = {
            type: 'text',
            text: response
          }
          client.reply_message(event['replyToken'], message)
        end

      end
    } 

    head :ok
  end
end
```

`hash_result = JSON.parse result` のところまで値を所得出来ているのですが、
`shops = hash_result["rest"]` のところで値が `nil` になりエラーが発生してしまいます。
構文ミス等探したのですが、見つけることが出来ず困ってます。
もしよろしければご回答いただけると幸いです。

Comment: 質問のタイトルは具体的に、今回の場合なら表示されたエラーメッセージに注目して組み立てると(回答してくれるかもしれない人の)目に止まりやすくなる気がします。 / 質問は後からでも [編集] できるので、必要に応じて見直してみてください。 参考: [良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

```
result = `curl -X GET https://api.gnavi.co.jp/RestSearchAPI/v3/?keyid=78d2d49f3aa8747a6cc03da01cf41bdd&category_s=RSFST08008&category_s=RSFST08009&#{place}`#ここでぐるなびAPIを叩く#{place}
```

外部コマンドに不備があります。 `&` を `\\&` に変更すれば動くのではないでしょうか？

Comment: ご指摘の通り外部キーのコマンドミスでした。本当にありがとうございます。

Comment: バッククォートリテラルはシェルが解釈するので & をエスケープする必要があったということみたいですね。